# Mostrar modal a determinada hora y que se cierre a una hora por defecto

Tags: php, javascript, html5, modal

Tengo un modal y quisiera que aparezca y desaparezca en un horario especifico, la idea es notificar al cliente que el sitio esta cerrado en determinado horario.

Por ahora tengo esto, pero no funciono.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  DisplayCurrentTime();
};

function DisplayCurrentTime() {
 var d = new Date();
 var hour = d.getHours();
 var min = d.getMinutes();

  if(hour <= 22 && min === 0){
    $("#horadl").modal("show");
  }else{
    if(hour <= 7 && min === 0){
      $("#horadl").modal("hide");
    }
  }
}
</script>


<div class="modal fade" id="horadl" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>-->
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Oops!</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align: justify;">
<br /><br /> En este momento nos encontramos descansando, esperamos contar con ustedes mañana.
<br /> Nuestro horario de atención es:<br />7:00 AM - 10:00 PM</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Aceptar</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Por favor algo de documentación, sugerencia o ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu HTML?

Comment: ¿El sitio estaría cerrado a partir de las 22 del usuario o de la zona horaria que tú elijas? Quiero decir: Si yo estoy en un país con una hora diferente a la tuya, si son mis 22 pero tus 20 (por ejemplo), ¿Debería estar cerrado o se cerraría a mis 24 y tus 22?

Comment: ahí preguntas la hora del cliente, lo que yo haría es un script con ayuda de ajax para estarle preguntando al servidor la hora y si está cerrado pues mostrar la modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrigiendo un poco esa lógica que tu planteas puedes lograr lo que deseas, siempre teniendo en cuenta que tomará el horario de la computadora del usuario:

```
if(hour >= 7 && hour <= 22){
    $("#horadl").modal("show");
  }else{ 
    $("#horadl").modal("hide");
  }
```

El problema de la solución que implementaste es que solo es TRUE la sentencia si da la hora en punto si no es la hora en punto el condicional no se ejecutará, es decir a las 7:00 es TRUE,pero a las 7:01 es FALSE en cambio como lo escribí ahora solo toma en cuenta la hora, no los minutos, si la hora es mayor o igual a 7 Y menos o igual a 22 lanzará la modal.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, efectivamente yo estaba mal lógicamente.